# Is there any way to convert the RGB of the ZK colorBox into HexDecimal

Tags: zk

I am using ZK colorbox in my application and i want to convert the RGB value of the `getRGB()` method of the `Colorbox` to hexdecimal.
is there any way i can do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`org.zkoss.zkex.zul.Colorbox.getColor()`](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/latest/zk/org/zkoss/zkex/zul/Colorbox.html#getColor%28%29) method.

Answer (score 0):

Try  to Convert each integer of `getRGB()` result array to hex with `arr[i].toString(16)`